# Customize the marker - MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've created a Simple Bar Chart using `MPAndroidChart`. For the purpose of Marker I'm extending `MarkerView`. I need a marker as shown in the git hub, like this:

[image]

But I'm not getting that arrow. So it is not looking like a comment, it's a rectangular box :/

[image]

In order to make it look like a comment box instead of a rectangular box which class I should use. I've checked `IMarker`, `MarkerImage` but not sure which I should proceed with.

And even `MPPointF` isn't working. Can't import the package

`import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF;`

Code:

```
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) { 
    tv_turnOver.setText("Turn over: " + (int) e.getVal());

    /*
    if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {

        CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;

        tv_label.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(ce.getVal(), 0, true));
    } else {

        tv_label.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(e.getXIndex(), 0, true));
    }*/

    //  super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
}
```

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Could you kindly help

Comment: It sounds like you are using the wrong version of the library because my MarkerViews display with the arrow in them. This would explain your problem with importing `MPPointF`. Make sure you are using version 3.0.1

Comment: I was using v2.1.6 :( checking the same with v3.0.1

Comment: After changing everything to latest version it's still the same. I've done this example: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivity.java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi/marker2.png

**Using an image as a background**

That's it...

That's it??!!!

Instead of the background colour 'Red', I've used this image to get that arrow.

Comment: If the content is more background is not showing properly on tip of bar

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have the latest version MPAndroidChart (3.0.1). Clone, build, and run the sample project on your device. You can see that the first example on the menu called "Line Chart - a simple demonstration of the linechart" has the highlight view you want. It looks like this:

[image: a picture of a LineChart in MPAndroidChart which shows a marker view that meets the OP's requirement]

The code is inside the sample project in [`LineChartActivity1`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java). The xml is the following:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The MarkerView is as follows:

```
package com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample.custom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.MarkerView;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Utils;
import com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample.R;

/**
 * Custom implementation of the MarkerView.
 *
 * @author Philipp Jahoda
 */
public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private TextView tvContent;

    public MyMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }

    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

        if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {

            CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;

            tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(ce.getHigh(), 0, true));
        } else {

            tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(e.getY(), 0, true));
        }

        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {
        return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
    }
}
```

And it is consumed like this:

```
MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
mv.setChartView(mChart); // For bounds control
```

Comment: I've done all that stuff @David. I was successfully getting the marker. The real trick(**only way**) behind that arrow is http://stackoverflow.com/a/41479610/2820534

Comment: And Thank you for making me realize that I wasn't using the current version