# Android MPChart How to show custom marker?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to customize the bar marker in Android MpChart library. Here is what I expected but do no know? How to show marker on the tip of the bar? I tried setting the background as image view with arrow marker at bottom but it will move if I switch between bars.

[image]

Comment: Please, look at this - it may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458190/customize-the-marker-mpandroidchart

Answer (score 0):

```
barChart.setMarker(new MarkerView(getActivity(),R.layout.tooltip){ // tooltip is layout you want to set as markerview, for background use a drawble
        @Override
        public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

               // set the total , prome etc here
                super.refreshContent(e, highlight);

        }
        @Override
        public MPPointF getOffset() {
            return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight()); // place the midpoint of marker over the bar
        }
    });
```

see for [more](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView) information